# Sending messages using aSmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm using aSmack and XMPP server to create a chat application. And I don't know but I can't send messages to myself. Can somebody help me with that?
I guess, "error" is in this line.

```
chat = org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(chatMessage.receiver + "@"
                                + "lucky" ,
                        chatMessages);
```

Is this code:

```
chatMessage.receiver + "@"
                                    + "lucky"
```

right?

Host name and Server name are "lucky".

Thank you.